# Difference between aspnet_Users, aspnet_Profile and aspnet_Membership tables in Sitecore

Tags: security, user-profile, membership-provider

Can someone please help me understand the use and difference between `aspnet_Users`, `aspnet_Profile` and `aspnet_Membership` tables in Sitecore?

And what sequence Sitecore follows to create user I mean does it 1st create user in `aspnet_Users` then Profile in `aspnet_Profile` and then uses `aspnet_Membership`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this subject better, it's best if you learn how ASP.Net Membership works first using Microsoft documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/tw292whz(v=vs.100)

The 3 tables you ask for, when you work with Sitecore:

1. `aspnet_Users` - it only stores users. The following columns:

- `UserId` (to match with other tables),
- `UserName` and
  -`LastActivityDate`columns
  are the only ones that most probably will be ever important to you.

2. `aspnet_Profile` table contains additional values for users. It has following columns:

- `UserId` to match users from `aspnet_Users` table
- `PropertyNames` containing names of the properties and their positions and size in other columns
- `PropertyValuesString` - containing values of string properties
- `PropertyValuesBinary` - containing values of properties which are not stored as strings.

3. `aspnet_Membership` table contains plenty of columns but you should be only interested in those:

- `UserId` - to match users from `aspnet_Users` table
- `Password` - encoded password
- `Email`
- `IsApproved`
- `IsLockedOut`

Knowing that, when you create a new user, Sitecore creates entries in all 3 tables in one SQL transaction (or at least one right after another). It creates row for user details in `aspnet_Users`, stores password and email in `aspnet_Membership` table and saves some properties like first name and last name in `aspnet_Profile` table.